# Add Context menu in Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex

How we add context menu in datagrid column header.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Context Menus require right click, and they capture the `MouseEvent.CLICK` event before you can (haven't tested it with event `priority` however, so try that).

So you need to add a [`flash.events.ContextMenuEvent`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/events/ContextMenuEvent.html) handler to the DataGrid (or a part of the datagrid like the header).  Or you can add a global one (that's what I do).

Then check what the current target is under the mouse.  You probably wont get the exact item (DisplayObject/UIComponent, etc) you're looking for just checking the event.relatedObject property and such, so your best bet is to use `stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)`.

Then once you get the object (or you find "this object is the one I want", you can set the context menu dynamically).

Something like this:

```
protected function updateTarget(event:ContextMenuEvent):void
{
    var targets:Array = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY))// or less accurately, event.mouseTarget;
    var target:DisplayObject = targets[targets.length - 1];
    if (target)
    {
        // array of ContextMenuItem objects based on the target
        var contextMenuItems:Array = getMyContextMenuItems(target);
        if (contextMenuItems)
        {
            var menu:flash.ui.ContextMenu = stage.contextMenu; // or another target
            var menuItems:Array = [];
            var i:int = 0, n:int = contextMenuItems.length;
            for (i; i < n; i++)
            {
                menuItems.push(contextMenuItems[i].getItem());
            }
            menu.customItems = menuItems;
            if (hideBuiltInItems)
                menu.hideBuiltInItems();
            target.contextMenu = menu;
        }
    }
}
```

Customize it as you need it :).

Hope that helps.